# How to get backtrace in libprocessgroup/processgroup.cpp?

Tags: android, c++, callstack, process-group

In Android, I want get the trace that call `processgroup.DoKillProcessGroupOnce()`, but I don't know how to use the CallStack.

```
#include <utils/CallStack.h>

static int DoKillProcessGroupOnce(const char* cgroup, uid_t uid, int initialPid, int signal) {
    android::CallStack::logStack("TRACE1");
```

But the log says that `TRACE1: CallStack::logStackInternal` is not linked.

It seems that: `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(getCurrentInternal) == 0`

```
#ifdef WEAKS_AVAILABLE
static CallStackUPtr ALWAYS_INLINE getCurrent(int32_t ignoreDepth = 1) {
    if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(getCurrentInternal) == 0) { //>>>>>>>
        ALOGW("CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null");
        return CallStackUPtr(nullptr);
    } else {
        return getCurrentInternal(ignoreDepth);
    }
}
```

I really need some help about how to get backtrace in `processgroup.cpp`.